# Debian iso image is too large to fit in a standard 700MB CD

Tags: debian, iso

```
debian-7.7.0-amd64-kde-CD-1
```

I downloaded the above from: http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/

... but it appears to be too large for a standard 700 MB CD according to my k3b.
 This doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can also make a bootable USB

Answer (score 3):

It's an image for burning on to a DVD-R (or USB flash), not CD-R. To quote from the Debian Live site's ["about the release images" page](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/):

> Each image is much smaller than the full set of CD/DVD images, but larger than the network install media. If you are installing from optical media, the standard and rescue images will fit on a CD, *whereas the others require a DVD.* [Emphasis added]

Answer (score 1):

Is this the page you are looking for http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.8.0/amd64/iso-cd/

What you have there is a DVD image. There are also minimum CD images, for network installs. You can also download by torrent etc, not just http. This is easier on the servers, faster, and more reliable.

Comment: derobert:Thanks. I misinterpreted the 'cdimage' portion of what the url meant.

Comment: richard; Bingo! ... that IS what I should have been looking for. Thanks

Comment: It is traditional to click the tick of the answer that you accept. Hope you enjoy this site more in the future.